# How to create manifest file for private assembly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I want to know how to create manifest for my c++ private assemblies. What I have done now is keeping a static manifest file(as show below) and embed it into the dll. The down side of this approach is that I cannot update the version number in the manifest file. I want to update the version in the manifest file with the version of dll.

Please advice me if anyone knows some details on creating manifest for "private assembly"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="MyCompany.MyDll" version="1.0.0.0"
                    processorArchitecture="x86" ></assemblyIdentity>  
</assembly>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just update it when you recompile. You'll have to be recompiling for the version number to increment anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray, Yes I am recompiling each time? But how do I change the version in the manifest file which is actually a separate file (no relation with code) ? I am specifying this manifest file in the "project settings->Manifest Tool->Input and output->Additional Manifest Files" to embed it into the dll.